# Editing Angular Table Element do not disappear

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, angular-ngmodel

ive got a little problem with my Table. The implemented options are, that i can change the name from the item with clicking on the td or to change it by clicking on the pencil - but it does not disappear when i click on the X (means exit the input). When i'll change the name, a toast message appears, but the input field wont close (what its supposed to do).

I am attaching a screenshot of the table item and the html and ts code, just to know what is going on. Thanks in advance and happy replying! :)

[input field (td)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKoYa.png)

It is the state when i have changed the name but the input field no longer closes!

```
                  <button
                      pButton
                      pRipple
                      class="p-button-outlined border-radius-0 bg-white p-button-icon-only p-button-default"
                      type="button"
                      id="cancel-edit-name"
                      (click)="cancel(group)"></button>

                  <button
                      pButton
                      pRipple
                      class="p-button-outlined p-button-icon-only bg-white border-radius-left-0 p-button-success"
                      type="button"
                      id="ok-edit-name"
                      (click)="onSubmit(group)"></button>


  onSubmit(group: Group) {
    if (group.name?.length > 0 && group.name.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_ \-]+$')) {
      group.active = false;
      this.groupService.updateGroup(group).subscribe(this.messageService.observe('groups.group.edit.success'));
    }
  }

  editGroup(group: Group) {
    group.active = true;
  }

  cancel(group: Group) {
    group.active = false;
  }


<input id="group-name-edit" type="text" [(ngModel)]="group.name" pInputText (keyup.enter)="onSubmit(group)" (keyup.esc)="cancel(group)">
```

Did i miss something or am i just blind..

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz with the minimal reproduction of the error?

Comment: hi @NarenMurali sorry i can't.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "the input field no longer closes" ? Do you mean lose focus ? If so you can call the blur function:

```
input.blur();
```

Comment: sorry, i mean.. the input field remains selected even if i select a different item - hope its clearer now.

Comment: Adding the blur call in your cancel function doesn't work ?
If you have not acces to your input element, you can also use: document.activeElement.blur();